# ReferenceError: timer is not defined at Timeout._onTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just started learning node js and I've got this error for 'timer' not being global.

```
var time = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    time += 2;
    console.log(time + " seconds have passed");
    if (time > 5) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: `timer` is not defined anywhere yet used in `clearInterval(timer)`. Try `var timer = setInterval(..`.

Answer (score 1):

you shall declare `timer` and set it to the result value of setInterval:

```
var time = 0;

const timer = setInterval(function() {
    time += 2;
    console.log(time + " seconds have passed");
    if (time > 5) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: ah, thanks man it works now  :)